# How is java REST service understood by other platforms

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Am new to the concept of REST web services and I have tried out some REST web services example using Jersey. My question here is , suppose if I have a REST web service written in java, how is it consumed by some other client? for example say its C#. These are two different language but how does C# know what kind of data is being returned by a java web service? I would like to know how this cross platform communication happens internally?

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question, say I request something and in response I get a XML, how do we standardize this? I mean how do we ensure the server sends the same XML format which is expected by the client?

Comment: `REST` plus `XML` is a bad idea. Folks have moved on from their SOAP experience . Few guidelines at [link](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) esp. subsection [JSON only responses](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#limiting-fields)

Comment: Service request and responses are standardized by writing validators and documentation.

Comment: Thanks a  lot sabir

Answer (score 2):

Different languages and platforms can communicate because they use a standard protocol: in this case REST is built upon HTTP, which is the same no matter the client (Java, C#, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Language dependency is eliminated mainly because of two things ,

1.REST Clients can be any client which can submit a HTTP request, written in any language. This is possible because REST uses HTTP protocol so server side will respond to any client that can ping at appropriate HTTP URL.

2.Response formats are language independent ( JSON , XML etc ) . As long as target language has capability to parse that response format, we are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

REST defines the transport layer and encoding specification which is completely independent on the programming language.

In the Java the method is supposed to return native object and the REST framework does the serialization to XML or JSON (actually anything but the mentioned are the most common).

On the client side, the client specifies the class which should be used to retrieve the data and does pretty much the opposite - goes field by field and reads the content and assigns it to native object. It uses that native object fields to guess the type of the field (string, int, double, date etc.).

Comment: We use  @Produces annotation to specify the type of data being returned from the service, my understanding is that this content type wil be used by the client from the response header to understand the type of data being returned. Am I right?

Comment: @DPH : Partially yes, it actually specifies content-type header which is used to determine what encoding is used to serialize and unserialize the data (JSON/XML/...). The native object type on the client side has to be still provided by the client code.